# Python: Creating a table, what does "none" mean?

Tags: python

Trying to build a basic multiplication table, and I keep getting these "none"s. What do they mean and how can I get rid of them?

```
    >>> def M(n):
...     i = 1
...     while i <= 6:
...             print i*n, '\t',
...             i = i +1
...     print

    >>> def printT():
...     w = 1
...     while w <= 6:
...             print M(w)
...             w = w + 1
... 

>>> printT()
1   2   3   4   5   6   
None
2   4   6   8   10  12  
None
3   6   9   12  15  18  
None
4   8   12  16  20  24  
None
5   10  15  20  25  30  
None
6   12  18  24  30  36  
None
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `print M(w)` with just `M(w)`. You are printing the return value of `M(w)` which is `None` since you are not returning anything from that function.

Comment: No. You invoke a function and print the function's return value. The function you invoke (M) prints something and returns the value None. Printing the value None outputs the characters "None" on the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

In your function, printT(), your print M(w) is returning nothing. The implicit return value for a function in python is None, which is what is printed during your loop.

Just re-write your function like this:

```
def printT():
    w = 1
    while w <= 6:
        M(w)
        w += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This 'none' occured for me too. I typed a function and tried to use it in another function. But i had written 'print calculation'. It should be 'return calculation'. So the second function gave 'none' error. Inspect my code:

```
def factoriel(n):
    i = 1
    calculation = float(n)     #if there is not 'float', the type would be int

    while i < n:
        calculation = calculation * i
        i += 1
    return calculation        #it was print at first try, so i got 'none'

x = factoriel(5)

print x, type(x)              #to check the result
```